# How to display rows of data from a MySQL database in Android fragment?

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-fragments

I'm trying to build a food menu app for my school. I will be entering the meal plan every week into a MySQL database. My app has a tabbed view with each fragment representing the day of the week.

I want to be able to display the corresponding day's menu on the corresponding fragment.

MainActivity.java

```
    package me.anshsehgal.lunchmenu;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;  //make all the variables

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager); //reference them
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new HomeFragment(),"M");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new MondayFragment(),"Tue");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new TuesdayFragment(),"W");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new WednesdayFragment(),"Thu");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new ThursdayFragment(),"F");   //adding fragments to view page adapter


        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_layout,menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        RelativeLayout main_view = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.anshLayout);

        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_settings:
                if(item.isChecked())
                    item.setChecked(false);
                else
                    item.setChecked(true);
                Intent i = new Intent(this,Settings.class);
                startActivity(i);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
}

}
```

MondayFragment.java

```
package me.anshsehgal.lunchmenu;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MondayFragment extends Fragment {


    public MondayFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_monday, container, false);
    }

}
```

Screenshot of app
[Sample of the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3ikn.jpg)

[Sample entry in table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S6l8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to access my sql directly in Android applications. You need to build rest API's which will expose required data in compressed manner(JSON). You can use any of the programming language like Java/C#/Scala/Node to expose rest end points.

If you are trying to store data which is user specific then you can use sql lite database